# How can I load HTML fixtures for Javascript unit tests in Karma with Mocha?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, karma-runner

Im searching for a decent test runner and unit testing framework for Javascript. My candidates are Karma and Mocha. Previously I used JsTestDriver, where adding HTML fixtures was easy, but I cant find a way how to load HTML fragments and access it from Mocha tests using Karma testrunner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final solution was [Karma testrunner](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/index.html) combined with [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), which has a [text plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/text) making the loading of HTML fixtures really easy.
A working example can be seen at this [Minesweeper game](https://github.com/blacksonic/minesweeper). It's still in development phase, but the the libraries and structuring are working.

Answer (score 3):

I have a demo that uses html fixtures with jasmine here and the demo description contains links to a screencast and github repo for running with Karma.  See [this link](http://codepen.io/jweden/details/Irmil).

Comment: we started using RequireJS and it solved loading html dependencies